# Adjective to qualify "No GUI"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

What adjective can we use to qualify something that has no (visual) Graphic User Interface?

For example, a bot, a script, a command line tool, ...

I am thinking of "headless", taken from "Chrome headless" running Google Chrome in script without graphic user interface. But I am not sure if I can use that for anything else than Chrome. Can I say, I made a "headless bot"? Also, the term is not intuitive for someone who does not know about Chrome headless.

I hope there is a better for "without GUI"

Comment: Surely a command line tool _has_ a user interface - the command line.

Comment: You're right, I have to precise GUI no UI (Graphic)

Comment: "headless" is used a lot for headless modes of a program that can be used both with a gui or as a command. I've never seen it used for a program that can only be used as a command. Also, note that there's a difference between a program that can be used from the command line by calling a single command; and a program that can be used from a terminal but will start an interactive session (even if that session doesn't have graphics)

Comment: Headless is used in Java to indicate the lack of a display device, keyboard, or mouse: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html. I seem to remember that initially some Java constructs required a display, but this changed subsequently. There is one of our moderators will know much better than me.

Comment: ["In the Beginning was the Command Line"](https://www.ridemybike.org/command1.pdf)

Comment: So to clarify, are you asking about things with a CLI or things that are *embedded*?

Comment: Correct. That's what I am asking

Comment: You can use their jargon; that's what they do.

Comment: Are you asking about a *terminal* or *textual* interface? Or no interface? The question isn't too clear, IMO.

Comment: "Command line" makes sense on desktop systems, and is often used by Microsoft for Windows apps with no GUI. But in an embedded setting with no terminal/CLI, it is less appropriate. There are also more specific terms like daemon, service, etc. Context would help.

Answer (score -1):

You would typically call it a **command-line** (or **command line**) program. This is how [cURL](https://curl.se/), [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) describe themselves.